# Is there a way to bulk submit URLs to Fetch as Google?

Tags: google-search-console, url, search-engine-indexing, fetch-as-google

Google is taking a while to re-index changes I have made to thousands of pages, so I want to use Fetch as Google to give it a prompt. However, you can only enter 1 URL at a time as standard.

Is there a way to bulk submit URLs to it?

Comment: Not what you're asking but you should consider submitting XML sitemaps.

Comment: I do already, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indirectly, **yes**:

1. Create a page with links to all the URLs you'd like re-crawled (like a sitemap) and add that to your website.*
2. Submit the URL to that page to *Fetch as Google*, selecting **Desktop** as the fetching strategy, as detailed here: [Use Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en&ref_topic=6066464).
3. Once Fetch as Google is complete, and within 4 hours time, from the *Fetches Table* next to the status of the fetch, select **Submit to Index**, then select **Crawl this URL and its direct links**, followed by **Submit**.

As indicated in [Ask Google to re-crawl your URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en&ref_topic=6066464), the above will:

> Submit the URL as well as all the other pages that URL links to for
>   re-crawling. You can submit up to 10 of requests of this kind per
>   month.

**As commented by John Mueller, you can also submit a sitemap file or a text file containing a list of URLs.*

Comment: @dan That is far superior to my idea! I will keep this in my rolodex of tricks.

Comment: You could also just create a sitemap file (or text URL-list file) and submit that.

Comment: @JohnMueller Thanks for your input here, added that to the answer.

Comment: @JohnMueller Thanks. I'm now trying to speed up de-indexation of pages; could I submit a sitemap of pages to de-index (I'm not sure if it's counter intuitive to point a re-crawl to pages to re-index?).

Comment: @Newmania sure, that works too.

Comment: @JohnMueller This is taking a really long time still. 21k pages removed from the index in 5 weeks, but 45k more still to be removed. I submitted http://www.rscpp.co.uk/please-crawl.txt on 14th June and see "URL and linked pages submitted to index". Anything further I can do to remove those?

Comment: Without a lastmodification date, those URLs aren't going to get crawled faster.

Comment: @JohnMueller thanks, how would the "text URL-list file" specify the lastmodification date? Or is it better to create a sitemap?

Also we are trying to get our AMP pages reindexed, and have submitted a similar txt file of URLS, but same issue in that only a small amount have been indexed so far.

Comment: Those tools seem to have vanished. Nowadays there's only a search bar in Google Webmaster to look for data about URLs in your own registered website's profile.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a sitemap (XML,`.txt`, HTML or RSS) allows bots to discover pages. If you need even faster submission, do it manually or some types of automation (using selenium).

Comment: Nice. I didn't know you could use `.txt` for sitemaps. I thought they had to be according to the [sitemap protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) only.