# GSC Sitemap Coverage questions

Tags: sitemap, duplicate-content, canonical-url

I recently noticed that my sitemap listed the urls in my site beginning with `http://` although the canonical tags of the page are `https://`, so I resubmitted my sitemap with the correct urls.

I am not sure if the above is the direct cause, but around the same time I noticed that many of my pages were categorized as

"Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical" in the new GSC tool.

I did a 'Fetch as Google' with the new https:// sitemap and requested indexing including all links as recommended in this [link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69230/is-there-a-way-to-bulk-submit-urls-to-fetch-as-google):

It has been about 5 days since I have submitted the new sitemap, but the number of urls in "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical" have not changed, and GSC shows that the coverage report was last updated 1/23/19.

[image]

The 'Inspect URL' section shows that the url is on Google, but the Coverage states

"Indexed, not submitted in sitemap" with the following details:

[image]

**Discovery**

Sitemaps
N/A

Referring page
http://[url]

**Crawl**

Last crawl
Jan 30, 2019, 7:35:59 PM

Crawled as
Googlebot desktop

Crawl allowed?
Yes

Page fetch
Successful

**Indexing**

Indexing allowed?
Yes

User-declared canonical
https://[url]

Google-selected canonical
Inspected URL

I have tried requested re-indexing for the duplicate urls, but the new https:// urls shows as being indexed, although the sitemap also contains the https:// url, I am still seeing the same results.

I currently have about 150 urls showing as indexed in the old GSC (as opposed to the 125 show in the image below), and hope to have the 170 or so other urls indexed as well.

Do I need to wait a bit longer? Or maybe I as missing something? The discrepancy between the http and https is my own guess - would there be another cause / solution to this issue?

Thank you for any help and guidance

PS: adding an image from the old GSC, I think the dip to about 0 was when I submitted the new `https://` sitemap

[image]

Comment: also judging from the consistent delta between the 'submitted' and 'index' urls, is there another approach I can take to get the duplicate urls indexed?

Comment: It took a year for Google index all the pages on my site with HTTPS when I chose them as the canonical.   Google is just slow at moving sites to HTTPS I think.